# Parent iframe URL

Tags: php, jquery, iframe

I'm using a 100% screen size iframe that redirects to another domain.
Basically you have a full screensize iframe and within that you see another domain which is which you operate.

The URL always reads from the inditial domain eg: www.iframedomain.com
The domain that is seen and used within the iframe is www.childdomain.com

Is there a way when in the above situation to change the URL on www.iframedomain.com using code from www.childdomain.com?

thx

Comment: terrible idea, what are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that in JavaScript

[Iframe payone redirect parent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4632604/iframe-payone-redirect-parent)

or [PHP "header (location)" inside IFRAME, to load in _top location?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2985353/php-header-location-isnide-iframe-to-load-in-top-location)

You can't do that in PHP.

Probably the idea is that only the client knows which iframe the child page is inside of, so the scripting has to be done client-side. While PHP knows the referrer, it can't control browser behavior to the extent you want?